# psql query and excel multiple cell parameters

Tags: excel, parameters, spreadsheet, psql

I have a spreadsheet that I grab quotes from with this query
SELECT distinct V_QUOTE_LINES.QUOTE_NO,  V_QUOTE_LINES.PART
FROM V_QUOTE_LINES V_QUOTE_LINES
WHERE (V_QUOTE_LINES.DATE_QUOTE)>? and V_QUOTE_LINES.quote_no = ?
and when in excel and I open the connection properties I can only select one cell to enter a quote number in to fetch the data.  I can't use multiple quote numbers in the cell seperated by a , or a ; ex. 123456, 123457 and display data for both quotes. Any help would be great.

Here is the sql query
SELECT distinct V_QUOTE_LINES.QUOTE_NO,  V_QUOTE_LINES.PART
FROM V_QUOTE_LINES V_QUOTE_LINES
WHERE (V_QUOTE_LINES.DATE_QUOTE)>? and V_QUOTE_LINES.quote_no = ?

and I choose the cell in parameters I want to enter the quote number in and a single quote number works fine.

I want to be able to enter multiple quote numbers and see the data for each quote number entered in my excel spreadsheet.

I have tried adding additional one of these (V_QUOTE_LINES.DATE_QUOTE)>? and V_QUOTE_LINES.quote_no = ? at the end of the quote to add additional cells to enter quote numbers but it will only return one cell entry at a time.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue myself.   Here is what I did to pass the values from excel to psql to get the data I wanted in the line of code V_QUOTE_LINES.quote_no = ? I removed the = and used in (?,?,?) and in excel for each ? parameter I just selected cells to enter the quote # I wanted to review.  Here is the full code now.  SELECT DISTINCT V_QUOTE_LINES.QUOTE_NO, V_QUOTE_LINES.PART
FROM V_QUOTE_LINES V_QUOTE_LINES
WHERE ((V_QUOTE_LINES.DATE_QUOTE)>?) AND (V_QUOTE_LINES.QUOTE_NO in (?,?,?,?))